# Discord Guild Commands not register

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, discord.js

I programmed a context menu handler a few days ago, but I made an error. Namely, the context menus overwrote all guild commands because they weren't exported at the same time.

Now my guild commands don't work anymore or just not for the guild on which I also loaded the context menus.

I've already tried to kick the bot but it doesn't help.

The order to upload the Guild Slash Commands is permanently on `pending`.

My Slash Command handler:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const chalk = require('chalk');

const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v10');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest')

const AsciiTable = require('ascii-table');
const table = new AsciiTable().setHeading('Slash Commands', 'Stats').setBorder('|', '=', "0", "0")

const TOKEN = "";
const CLIENT_ID = "1034931814717980682";
const GUILD_ID = "921103666818191440";

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(TOKEN);

module.exports = (client) => {
    const GUILD = client.guilds.cache.get(GUILD_ID)
    const slashCommands = [];

    fs.readdirSync('./slashCommands/').forEach(async dir => {
        const files = fs.readdirSync(`./slashCommands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for(const file of files) {
                const slashCommand = require(`../slashCommands/${dir}/${file}`);
                slashCommands.push({
                    name: slashCommand.name,
                    description: slashCommand.description,
                    type: slashCommand.type,
                    options: slashCommand.options ? slashCommand.options : null,
                    default_permission: slashCommand.default_permission ? slashCommand.default_permission : null,
                    default_member_permissions: slashCommand.default_member_permissions ? PermissionsBitField.resolve(slashCommand.default_member_permissions).toString() : null
                });
            
                if(slashCommand.name) {
                    client.slashCommands.set(slashCommand.name, slashCommand)
                        table.addRow(file.split('.js')[0], '✅')
                } else {
                        table.addRow(file.split('.js')[0], '⛔')
                }
        }
        
    });
    console.log(chalk.red(table.toString()));

    (async () => {
            try {
                await rest.put(
    GUILD_ID ?
    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, GUILD_ID) :
    Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), 
    { body: slashCommands }
);

                console.log(chalk.yellow('Slash Commands • Registered'))
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
    })();
};
```

The lines which always on pending:

```
await rest.put(
GUILD_ID ? Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, GUILD_ID) : Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID),
{body: slashCommands}
);
```

Comment: Can you provide the error which you are getting? And what exactly do you mean by "__always on pending__"?

Comment: @DarshanB I dont get any errors, but then I make the rest.put() function in a console.log() function it gives me an pending { } back. So I think it try is to load the commands but dont get it.

Comment: oh, it means you're supposed to `await` your function. Use `await rest.put(..`

Comment: @DarshanB but I'm already using `await rest.put(…)` ?

Comment: the commands don't register at all? or are there any errors being thrown?